# Surjectivity of a norm map over $ \mathbb{Q} $

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory, rational-points

Suppose $ (L/L') $  is an galois extension , where  both fields are extension of $Q$ of $\dim n $ and $\dim n^{'}$ respectively.Suppose we consider the norm map $ Nr_{(L/L')} :L \rightarrow L' $. Suppose $ U $ be a subspace of L' of $\dim  n'-1 $ then what will be the maximum dimensional subspace  in $L$ such that norm of every elements belong to this subspace ? Can we say anything about the pre-image of this subspace?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were a reasonable answer to this question. You are mixing a multiplicative map, highly non linear (the norm), which something additive (subspaces of $L$ and $L'$) . Could you please explain the context and the motivation? Did you work out some examples ?

Comment: Actually if we take finite field  then the norm map is subjective but I don't have any idea about the subjectivity condition  valid in $\mathbb Q  $ or some extension.

Comment: If i remember properly, ihe norm map is never surjective for number fields, but i don't see the relation with your question, since you are asking about the values abutting into a hyperplane. What is really your question? Once again, what is the context/motivation? did you work out examples ?

Comment: I have mentioned  hyperplane  because I thought norm map is surjective , I thought as trace map, but I know that norm map is not a linear. Here you are saying already that subjectivity  never happens in number fields. So I think  it has no specific  answer.. Anyway can you provide me the topic where I can found norm map is not surjective  in number field

Comment: Then actually  the example of non surjective  map,helps us to finding the counter examples.

Comment: If $L'\subset\mathbb{R}$ and complex conjugation induces an automorphism on $L$, then $N_{L/L'}(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in L$. This provide you with plenty of examples where the norm is not surjective.